# How can I create an Ember object to send Google Drive API requests?

Tags: ember.js, google-drive-api

Basically, I need to create an Ember wrapper for the Google Drive API JavaScript client library.

Answer (score 1):

Pulling information for various sources, here is a Gist with some information that hopefully will help others:

https://gist.github.com/monocle/9539722

It's not perfect, but it get's the job done for now. This will make creating an Ember Data Adapter for Google Drive files easier.

Comment: I'm doing something very similar for AngularJS. A couple of things to consider: (1) remember to deal with list results that span multiple continuation pages, (2) you might want to make how the access_token is retrieved, configurable because there are many different approaches.